# Avoiding support code for SVA sequence to handle pipelined transaction

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

Let's say we have a protocol that says the following. Once the master sets `req` to `fill`, the slave will signal 4 transfers via `rsp`:

[image]

An SVA sequence for this entire transaction would be (assuming that the slave can insert `idle` cycles between the `trans` cycles):

```
req == fill ##1 (trans [->1]) [*4];
```

Now, assume that the master is allowed to pipeline requests. This would mean that the next `fill` is allowed to start before the 4 `trans` cycles are done:

[image]

The SVA sequence from above won't help, because for the second `fill` it's going to wrongly match 4 `trans` cycles, leaving the last `trans` "floating". It would need to start matching `trans` cycles only after the ones for the previous `fill` have been matched.

The sequence needs global information not available in a single evaluation. Basically it needs to know that another instance of it is running. The only way I can think of implementing this is using some RTL support code:

```
int num_trans_seen;
bit trans_ongoing;
bit trans_done;
bit trans_queued;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
  if (!rst_n) begin
    num_trans_seen;
    trans_ongoing <= 0;
    trans_done <= 0;
    trans_queued <= 0;
  end
  else begin
    if (trans_ongoing)
      if (num_trans_seen == 3 && req == trans) begin
        trans_done <= 1;
        if (req == fill || trans_queued)
          trans_queued <= 0;
        else
          trans_ongoing <= 0;
        num_trans_seen == 0;
      end
    else
      if (trans_queued) begin
        trans_queued <= 0;
        trans_ongoing <= 1;
      end

    if (trans_done)
      trans_done <= 0;
  end
```

The code above should raise the `trans_ongoing` bit while a transaction is ongoing and pulse `trans_done` in the clock cycle when the last `trans` for a `fill` is sent. (I say should because I didn't test it, but this isn't the point. Let's assume that it works.)

Having something like this, one could rewrite the sequence to be:

```
req == fill ##0 (trans_ongoing ##0 trans_done [->1]) [*0:1]
  ##1 (trans [->1]) [*4];
```

This should work, but I'm not particularly thrilled about the fact that I need the support code. There is a lot of redundancy in it, because I basically re-described a good chunk of what a transaction is and how pipelining works. It's also not as easily reusable. A `sequence` can be placed in a package and imported somewhere else. The support code can only be placed in some module and reused, but it's a different logical entity than the package that would store the sequence.

The question here is: is there any way to write the pipelined version of the sequence while avoiding the need for support code?

Comment: Is it easy to decode the difference between rsp's idle and trans?

Comment: What I understood that, If another "fill" arrives between a "fill" and 4 "trans" cycles, then the later "fill" will be simple ignored (In the image, 2nd "fill" will be ignored). Kindly comment on my understanding.

Comment: @KaranShah Nope, The second fill has it's 4 "trans" cycles start after the ongoing ones are finished.

Comment: @Greg Yes, they're enumerated types. In one clock you see IDLE, in another you see TRANS. To figure out that a TRANS happened is the easy part. Mapping TRANS cycles to the appropriate FILL is the difficult part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like rsp is always idle before the trans starts. If rsp's `idle` is a constant value and it is a value that `trans` will never be, then you could use:

```
req == fill ##0 (rsp==idle)[->1] ##1 trans[*4];
```

The above should work when the pipeline supports 1 to 3 stages.

For a 4+ deep pipeline, I think you need some auxiliary code. The success/fail blocks of the assertion can be used to incompetent the count of completed `trans`; this saves you from having write additional RTL. A local variable in the property can be used to sample the fill's count value. The sampled value will be used as a criteria to start sampling the expected trans pattern.

```
int fill_req;
int trans_rsp;
always @(posedge clk, negedge rst_n) begin
  if(!rst_n) begin
    fill_req <= '0;
    trans_rsp <= '0;
  end
  else begin
    if(req == fill) begin
      fill_req <= fill_req + 1; // Non-blocking to prevent risk of race condition
    end
  end
end

property fill_trans();
  int id;
  @(posedge clk) disable iff(!rst_n)
  (req == fill, id = fill_req) |-> (rsp==idle && id==trans_rsp)[->1] ##1 trans[*4];
endproperty

assert property (fill_trans()) begin
  // SUCCESS
  trans_rsp <= trans_rsp + 1; // Non-blocking to prevent risk of race condition
end
else begin
  // FAIL
  // trans_rsp <= trans_rsp + 1; // Optional for supporting pass after fail
  $error("...");
end
```

FYI: I haven't had time to fully test this. It should at least get you in the right direction.

---

---

I experimented a bit more and found a solution that might be more to your liking; no support code.

The equivalent of `trans[->4]` is `(!trans[*] ##1 trans)[*4]` per [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 16.9.2 *Repetition in sequences*. Therefore we can use the local variables to detect new fill requests with the expanded form. For example the following sequence

```
sequence fill_trans;
  int cnt;                                // local variable
  @(posedge clk)
  (req==FILL,cnt=4) ##1 (                 // initial request set to 4
    (rsp!=TRANS,cnt+=4*(req==FILL))[*]    // add 4 if new request
    ##1 (rsp==TRANS,cnt+=4*(req==FILL)-1) // add 4 if new request, always minus 1
  )[*] ##1 (cnt==0);                      // sequence ends when cnt is zero
endsequence
```

Unless there is another qualifier not mentioned, you cannot use a typical `assert property();` because it will start new assertion threads each time there is a fill request. Instead use an `expect` statement, which allows waiting on property evaluations ([IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 16.17 *Expect statement*).

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if(req==FILL) begin
    expect(fill_trans);
  end
end
```

I tried recreating your describe behavior for testing https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5QLs

Comment: This assumes that there can't be `idle` cycles between the 4 `trans` cycles of a transaction, but this isn't the case. I guess I didn't really understand your previous question that asked whether `idle` is easy to differentiate from `trans`.

Comment: Your waveform didn't have idle between the 4 trans, so I simplified `(trans [->1]) [*4]`. If idle is allowed between trans of the same fill request, then the second example would still work after modified. The `id==trans_rsp` will block sampling of a set of trans until the prior finished. I asked about distinguishing `trans` & `idle` because I needed to understand your protocol. I have seen some protocols where rsp's meaning is based on a bit(s) qualifier and others that can only be determined from its relative position.

Comment: The second example uses support code, though, which is exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: A pure SVA might not be possible. Can you add another waveform showing worse case? Is there any additional qualifiers to block, gate, or queue the collection?

Comment: I get what you did there with the `expect`, though it requires a few takes to fully understand. The bottom line is that it's not really possible to do it using composition of simple sequences. (By simple sequence I mean sequences that model a single transaction, like `trans[->4]`, instead of having to hard code pipelining into them.)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be achieved with 2 assertions as below.

For 1st image -

```
(req == fill) && (rsp == idle) |=> ((rsp == trans)[->1])[*4]
```

For 2nd image -

```
(req == fill) && (rsp == trans) |=> ((rsp == trans)[->1])[*0:4] ##1 (rsp == idle) ##1 ((rsp == trans)[->1])[*4]
```

One issue is that if there are continuous "fill" requests on each cycle (consecutive 4 "fill" requests, without any intermediate "idle"), then the 2nd assertion will not calculate "trans" cycles for each "fill" requests (instead it'll only be completed on the 2nd set of "trans" cycles itself).

I could not modify the assertion for the given bug, as of now.

Comment: Not correct. Notice that I said that the slave can insert `idle` cycles between `trans`. If would be easy if `trans` cycles came in contiguous packets.

Comment: @Tudor Modified the assertion, and actually there is an another case, when the 2nd assertion will not properly behave.

Comment: When `req` comes, during a `trans` cycle it's clear that it's pipelined. Even then, though, you can't know in which of the 4 cycles it came. When `req` comes during an `idle` cycle, you can't know whether it's `idle` because the pipeline is empty or if it's an `idle` between two `trans` cycles.

Comment: Yes, but when req comes during idle cycle, we can certainly know that the there must be 4 trans cycles after idle. So the 1st assertion should be true irrespective of whether it is pipelined req or normal req.

Comment: @KaramShah No, that's false. You can't say where you are with a request (after a finished one or during one) simply by looking at `rsp`.